# Postgresql psycopg2 : 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a simple DB data manipulation routine that throws "updateBestandInDB Error 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'" which is a mistery to me.

```
def updateBestandInDB(conn,bestandID,free,used,total):
    sql = 'UPDATE "Bestand" SET "free" = %s, "used" = %s, "total" = %s, "time" = %s WHERE "id" = %s;'
    retVal = False
    try:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(sql,(free,used,total,datetime.now(),uuid.UUID(bestandID)))
        # get the modified id back
        #bestand_id = curs.fetchone()[0]
        #print('Return from updateBestandInDB :', bestand_id)
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        retVal = True
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("updateBestandInDB Error")
        print(error)
    finally:
        # close communication with the database
        curs.close()
        return retVal
```

None of the parameters used is a list. free, used and total are float.
Thanks for your comments.

I have searched stackoverflow and google all over but none of the solutions seems to fit as always lists are somehow involved, which is not the case here - at least not visible for me.

Comment: `uid = uuid.UUID(['{12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678}'])  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. So I'm betting `bestandID` is a `list`.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I was unaware that it might be considered a list. What I have done is

sql = 'SELECT id FROM "Bestand" WHERE "ticker" = %s AND "exchange" = %s AND "marker" = %s;'
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(sql,(symbol,exchange,marker,))
retVal = curs.fetchall()
This reVal, being the uuid from DB, has been passed to the above function as bestandID.
Does this means that somewhere in between it has been transformed into a list or would I have to store it in a different way (with a cast)?

Comment: Confirmed, bestandID has format [('ea9b7793-c35a-4795-be3e-e5a3044529f6',)] and this is the way it is read from the postgresql DB. I have now unpacked it with bestandID[0][0] but still it would be great to understand what's going on in the background here.

Comment: Not that hard to understand the docs [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) spell it out: *fetchall() Fetch all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning them as a list of tuples. An empty list is returned if there is no more record to fetch.*

Answer (score 0):

So do one thing to make yourself clear, you meant free, used and total are float. Okay let it be, then for bestandID, give direct value
like ('1234'or 1234), either string or int but only single element.
if it runs fine means, then surly the error will be in bestandID only.
For further clarification give bestandID value like ['1234'], then definitely you will understand the mistake.
Hope, this helps you.